# MongoDB não acha registro de alguns nomes

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, mongodb

Estou puxando alguns dados do MongoDB com o CodeIgniter e me deparei com uma coisa estranho... Alguns registros são encontrados e outros não. Debugando o código eu vi que o problema era o nome que ele está procurando, mas parece ser por causa de algum caractere. Meu código:

```
$aggregate = array(
                 array('$match'=>array('culturaNormatizada'=>$cultura, 'ano'=>(int)$ano, 'albaPotential'=>$alba)),
                 array('$group'=>array('_id'=>'$'.$regiao))
                 );
$query = $this->mongo_db->aggregate('business_view_final', $aggregate);
```

O dado que ele não consegue encontras (as vezes) é o da variável **$alba**. O nome **Camp-D  (Raio)** ele não consegue encontrar, mas existe no banco de dados na coluna **albaPotential**. Trocando esse nome, colocando outro como por exemplo **NonGrass** (que é outro registro) acha normalmente.

Parece ser não sei se é o `-` ou o `( )`, mas ele não contra por causa de algum caractere.

Answer (score 0):

Existem vários caracteres que se usam como hífen, pode ser que não esteja coincidindo com o que está no documento.

Veja aqui alguns caracteres diferentes que às vezes podem se confundir: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode

Experimente copiar e colar o valor do jeito que está no documento, para ter certeza que é o mesmo caractere.

Você também pode usar expressões regulares em uma consulta ao MongoDB, para tolerar diferenças como maiúsculas e outros caracteres, ou mesmo para procurar um valor que *contenha* uma palavra. Veja alguns exemplos:

Texto exato:

`{$match: {"albaPotential": "Camp-D (Raio)"}}`

Contém:

`{$match: {"albaPotential": /Raio/}}`

Contém, tolerando maiúsculas e minúsculas:

`{$match: {"albaPotential": /raio/i}}`

Veja mais sobre expressões regulares mais complexas, aqui: http://turing.com.br/material/regex/introducao.html